# Does LINQ Where clause honor order?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, where-clause

When I use a LINQ Where clause, does the returned list of items honor the order they were in the original list?

Comment: can u post some code ? and desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where processes items in the order `IEnumerable<T>` gives. If you query an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` thats keeps the order in which they are inserted (such as `List<T>`), then you keep the order. If you query a `HashTable<T>` for example, order is not guaranteed.

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't necessarily keep items in the order they were inserted. It does that if you use only `Add()`, but there are other ways to insert into it, like `Insert()`.

Comment: @svick: Well, kind of. Insert allows you to insert at any position in the list, but this does not change the ordering of other elements. Sure, if one _really_ needs an ordered list at all times, he would use `SortedList<T>`, but the point here is about how Where method iterates through

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the collection being queried has its `GetEnumerator` is implemented.  If `GetEnumerator` iterates through the collection in the order added, then it will honor order.

**UPDATE**:

Here's an example that I put together with LINQPad:

```
var items = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5 };
items.Insert(3, 100);

(from i in items
 where i > 2
 select i).Dump();
```

RESULT:

```
3 
100
4
5
```

So, the Where clause honors the order of the items in the list since List's [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) starts at the first item in the list and proceeds through the end.

Comment: The question is not about the order the items were added to the list, but about the order they *are* in the list.

Comment: @svick that's why I believe the answer deals with the list's GetEnumerator implementation.  A List<T>'s GetEnumerator will start at the first item in the collection and then proceed in order through the end.  So the order of the list will be returned by a call to`Where`.  The question was kind of vague, so I was kind of generic in my response.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ `where` clause is translated into a call of `Where()` method. If your list implements `IEnumerable<T>` and there is no better `Where()` method (there isn't, under most circumstances), it means [the extension method `Enumerable.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) is called.

Weirdly enough, that method is not documented as returning the items in order, but that's what it does in practice and I think you can rely on that.

If for the collection in question, some other implementation of `Where()` is used (most notably, for `IQueryable<T>`, it's [`Queryable.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx)) you don't have this guarantee anymore and `where` doesn't have to honor any sort of order. For example, SQL providers typically don't.